# Can't load module in Node console using symlinks

Tags: node.js

I'm on cygwin to do unix commands on win7 (launched cygwin.bat in windows cmd prompt).

My project directories are created in root like this:

```
$ mkdir -p app/models
$ mkdir -p app/node_modules
```

Then the symlink is created:

```
$ cd app/node_modules
$ ln -sf ../models
```

Back on the `/app/` directory, I go into Node console to launch the module located in
`app/models/movie.js`:

```
Movie = require('models/movie');
```

But I get the following error:

```
Cannot find module 'models/movie'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that cygwin doesn't really create actual symlinks by default. I had to create native NTFS symlinks using `export CYGWIN="winsymlinks:native"`

Answer (score 0):

`ln` takes 2 arguments, not one.

Comment: actually, no. If you input one argument your current command line directory becomes the target and your argument is the source. Two arguments are as you expect